# Changing Header for Concurrent Requests (Guzzle)

Tags: php, concurrency, guzzle, guzzle6

I am unable to change the request headers when making async requests.

```
$requests = function ($total) {
    $uri = 'https://www.example.com';
    $headers = [
        'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
        'X-Foo'      => ['Bar', 'Baz']
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
       yield new Request('GET', $uri, $headers); //Does not work
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(2), [
    'concurrency' => 5,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
        // this is delivered each successful response
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
        // this is delivered each failed request
    },
]);
```

I believe I have tried all of the examples provided in the [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests) and have been able to change the headers for all of them except the concurrent examples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this post is 2 years old by now but I am finding myself with the same question

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how I did this. I know this site wasn't any help. Checkout reddit.

Answer (score 0):

I may have gotten this to work, but not under the conditions that I was hoping for.

```
$headers = ['User-Agent' => 'Bar'];
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/']);

$promises = [
    'image' => $client->getAsync('/page1',
        ['User-Agent' => "test"]
    ),
    'png'   => $client->getAsync('/page2'),
];

$results = Promise\unwrap($promises);

$results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
```

I believe this works, because in this instance I am using the Client object rather than creating my own request (as I did in the other one). I'm not entirely sure about this. So if anyone can provide any further insight, that would be helpful.